# How we get the List objects in backward direction?

Tags: java, list, iterator

Hi i am getting List object that contains pojo class objects of the table. in my case i have to show the table data in reverse order. mean that, for ex
i am adding some rows to particular table in database when i am added recently, the data is storing at last row in table(in database). here i have to show whole content of the table in my jsp page in reverse order, mean that what i inserted recently have to display  first row in my jsp page.

here my code was like,

```
List lst = tabledate.getAllData();//return List<Table> Object
Iterator it = lst.iterator();
MyTable mt = new MyTable();//pojo class
while(it.hasNext())
{
     mt=(MyTable)it.next();
     //getting data from getters.
     System.out.println(mt.getxxx());
     System.out.println(mt.getxxx());
     System.out.println(mt.getxxx());
     System.out.println(mt.getxxx());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an iterator in this case. You will need to use index based access:

```
int size = lst.size();
for (int i=size - 1; i >= 0; i --)
{
  MyTable mt = (MyTable)lst.get(i);
  ....
}
```

Btw: there is no need to create a new MyTable() before the loop. This is an instance that will be thrown away immediately and serves no purpose.

Comment: If it's a LinkedList, this will take O(n^2) time instead of O(n)

Comment: Agreed. That's why `ListIterator` would be better ;)

Answer (score 9):

Use a [`ListIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to iterate through the list using `hasPrevious()` and `previous()`:

```
ListIterator it = lst.listIterator(lst.size());
while(it.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(it.previous());
}
```

Comment: @a_horse I love it when OP chooses the "worse" answer. Oh well. :-/

Comment: Well, your answer is wrong. It should say ListIterator it = lst.listIterator(lst.size());

Comment: @adamax Of course, how could I miss that! Thanks for pointing it out.